# Complex roots of the polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

In C[x] one of the roots of the polynomial $V(x)$ is $X1=-1+i$. Find the remaining roots of $V(x)$.

*I'm so sorry for the picture, but I need extra help with it. Hope you understand me.*

*Probably my attempt is not true, can someone help me how to solve it?*

[image]

Comment: What its meant that the conjugate $-1-i$ is also a zero of the polynomial.

Comment: @Wuestenfux I understand it and I noted it on my paper. The second polynomial was founded by definition I have problems with 4 others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best I can decipher, you are asked for the complex roots of the polynomial $$V(x)=x^6+2x^5+2x^4+3x^2+6x+6.$$

You are given that one of the roots is $x_1=-1+i.$

Since coefficients are real, you correctly deduce that the complex conjugate $x_2=-1-i$ is also a root.

$(x - (-1+i))(x-(-1-i))=x^2+2x+2$ therefore divides $V(x),$ and the quotient is $x^4+3$; that can be seen by inspection, though you did long division.  So we are left to find the roots of $x^4+3$.

If $x^4=-3$ then $x^2= \pm \sqrt3i.$ Solutions of $x^2=\sqrt3i$ are $$x_{3,4}=\pm\sqrt[4]3\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}$$ (it doesn't make sense to write $\sqrt i$) and solutions of $x^2=-\sqrt3i$ are $$x_{5,6}=\pm\sqrt[4]3\frac{1-i}{\sqrt2}.$$

Comment: Please, can you show me how did you solve it for x3,4 and x5,6? I have no idea how did you get these answers.

Comment: If you don’t know how to take roots of complex numbers using polar coordinates, you could get the solution by letting $x_{3,4}=a+bi$ which implies $x_{3,4}^2=(a^2-b^2)+2abi=\sqrt 3 i,$ which implies $a^2=b^2$ and $2ab=\sqrt 3$ and solving for the real coefficients $a$ and $b$, and I hope now you can see how to get $ x_{5,6} $ too

Comment: Thanks a lot, i got it